# Как выровнять элементы по правому краю?

Tags: css, выравнивание

https://jsfiddle.net/jde24ab4/

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="ul_header">
        <li><a href="index.html">Один</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Два</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Три</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Четыре</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul_header_right">
        <div style="float:right; margin-top: 15px; height:30px; border: 1px solid #0088cc; border-radius: 3px;"><li><a href="index.html">Регистрация</a></li></div>
        <div style="float:right;"><li><a href="index.html">Вход</a></li></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a{
  color: #0088cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
color: #0088cc; /* Цвет посещенных ссылок */
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #0088cc;
text-decoration: underline;;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4c5d6e;
}



#header{
background-color: #fff;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
border-bottom: solid 4px black;
}

.ul_header{
margin:0;
padding-left: 300px;
float: left;
}

.ul_header li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}

.ul_header_right{
  margin:0;
  float: right;
}

.ul_header_right li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Нужно выровнять элементы Регистрация и Вход по правому краю. Пробовал использовать параметры float:right, но проблема в том, что текст Регистрация выпадает из div вокруг него. Почему так? И еще элементы выводятся не в том порядке, как в HTML коде. Возможно это не правильный способ выровнять элементы по правой стороне? Как правильно их выровнять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас не валидный html код.

Не правильно:  `ul>div>li`

Правильно: `ul>li`

Для `#header` задано `line-height: 60px;` свойство распространяется и на все внутренние блоки, поэтому чтобы не вылазила надпись "Регистрация" - стоит задать `li` (или другой обертке)  `line-height: 30px;` (т.к. `height: 30px;` )

```css
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a{
  color: #0088cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
color: #0088cc; /* Цвет посещенных ссылок */
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #0088cc;
text-decoration: underline;;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4c5d6e;
}



#header{
background-color: #fff;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
border-bottom: solid 4px black;
}

.ul_header{
margin:0;
padding-left: 300px;
float: left;
}

.ul_header li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}

.ul_header_right{
  margin:0;
  float: right;
}

.ul_header_right li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}

.wrap-li {
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
    border-radius: 3px;
```

```html
<div id="header">
 <ul class="ul_header">
  <li><a href="index.html">Один</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Три</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Четыре</a></li>
 </ul>
  
 <ul class="ul_header_right">
  <li class="wrap-li"><a href="index.html">Регистрация</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Вход</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Все выравнивается.

Comment: В вашем примере нет дива вокруг Регистрации и текст вообще опущен вниз. Это не решение проблемы, удалять див обводку) Мне это нужно.

Comment: Добавлять обводку для li внутри ul - не валидно (не правильно), вроде доступно писала ответ.

Comment: Я это понял, там не в li и ul дело.
Вот без списка пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/pyfpywps/
Все равно регистрация почему-то вылезает из div

Comment: А в этом случае у Вас #header задано line-height: 60px; (распространяется на все вн. блоки) поэтому ссылка внутри блока по-умолчанию тоже имеет line-height: 60px; и не влазит в блок с фиксированной шириной в 30px; 
Задавайте дополнительно div (c ссылкой внутри) - line-height: 30px; 

А выравнивание, чтобы шло по порядку (регистрация, а потом вход) дополнительно нужно оборачивать еще в обертку (float:right)  и внутри нее уже выравнивать (регистрация - float: left; вход - float: right;).

Comment: Низкий вам поклон)